# Stop terminal in list execution

Tags: python-2.7

If I have a list say `uinput = str(raw_input("Enter you input : a|b|c|d|quit"))`
I want when I choose only a then after execution of a it should ask for "press any key to continue" and if I choose a|b|c then when c executes then it should ask for "press any key to continue" and quit option it should give this prompt.

Please help me how can we do this. Appreciate your help

Thanks

Comment: `uinput` is a string, not a list.

Comment: @ DeepSpace yes correct sorry. If I do as uinput1 = uinput.split("|")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
def foo():
    usr_input = raw_input("Enter you input : a|b|c|d|quit\n")
    usr_input_list = usr_input.split('|')

    length_of_list = len(usr_input_list)

    for usr_input_element in usr_input_list:
        if usr_input_element == 'a':
            if length_of_list == 1:  # Only if there's only an 'a' in list
                press_any_key_to_continue()
        if usr_input_element == 'c':
            if length_of_list > 1:  # If there is other things than 'c' in list
                press_any_key_to_continue()
        if usr_input_element == 'quit':
            exit()

def press_any_key_to_continue():
    this_variable_will_not_be_used = raw_input("Press any key to continue\n")
    print("Now it will continue")
```

If you input "a|c|b|a|quit|d"
it will create a list that looks like this

> ['a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'quit', 'd']

and the length of that list is then: `6`

And then the for-loop will go through the list, one by one.

---

Or you can do it in this way:

```
for usr_input_element in usr_input_list:
    if length_of_list == 1:  # Only if there's only an 'a' in list
        if usr_input_element == 'a':
            press_any_key_to_continue()
        if usr_input_element == 'c':
            press_any_key_to_continue()

    if length_of_list > 1:  # If there is other things than 'c' in list
        if usr_input_element == 'a':
            press_any_key_to_continue()
        if usr_input_element == 'c':
            press_any_key_to_continue()

    if usr_input_element == 'quit':
        exit()
```

But notice that then you have to put all if statements of them elements inside both `if length_of_list == 1:` and `if length_of_list > 1:`.

Comment: OuuGii thanks. Yes I am aware about this. But what to put this in my above senerio

Comment: @Ritesh Do you want the usr to input things untill he inputs 'quit'?

Comment: Thank you for your responce. I want as if I choose only a then after execution it shoud prompt for continue and if multiple option like a|b|c then press any key to continue prompt should occur ony after c element execution.

Comment: Updated @Ritesh, Is that what you wanted? By adding and using the length of the list you can decide what to do with the inputs.

Comment: thanks in a bunch. Thanks what I wanted. But do I need to if condition for each element. In case if choose only b or c ?

Comment: Updated again @Ritesh.